# Square wave generator. Using timers to adjust frequency. microchip MPLAB

Tags: c++, microchip, mplab

I want to avoid the `__delay_ms` functions and start using timers.

For now i have a very simple project. Generate a square wave with  25% precent duty cycle, and only control the frequency of it between a range of 0 and 5khz with a potentiometer on an analog input.

I created the code below but is doesnt work at all.

```
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000   // Oscillator frequency (4MHz)

void main() {

    while(1) {
        // Read the value of the potentiometer on pin RA0 (AN0)
        ADCON0 = 0b00000001; // Select RA0 as analog input
        ADCON0bits.GO_nDONE = 1; // Start the ADC conversion
        while (ADCON0bits.GO_nDONE); // Wait for the conversion to complete

        // Calculate the frequency based on the potentiometer value
        uint16_t potValue = ADRESH << 8 | ADRESL;
        uint16_t frequency = 100 + (potValue / 1024.0) * 400; // 100Hz to 500Hz, depending on the potentiometer value

        // Generate a square wave on RC2 (pin 17)
        T2CON = 0x00;       // Turn off Timer2
        TMR2 = 0;           // Set Timer2 counter to 0
        PR2 = (_XTAL_FREQ / (4 * frequency)) - 1; // Calculate PR2 value for the desired frequency
        T2CONbits.T2CKPS = 0b11; // Prescaler 1:16
        T2CONbits.TMR2ON = 1;   // Turn on Timer2

        // Wait for a short time (optional)
        __delay_ms(100);
    }
}
```

I hope some can help me a little bit with pointing me in how such a function would work.

Comment: what exactly is the meaning of "doesnt work at all" ? What happens when you compile and run the code? What should happen instead?

Comment: Well, you started a timer, but I can't find out what happens when the timer expires? I think you are missing an ISR callback somewhere. Or was it left out of the example?

Comment: @BasVisscher: Timers can do useful things besides generate interrupts.  Question says "Generate a square wave", which most timers on most microcontrollers can do directly.  But you're definitely correct that the "what happens" needs to be correctly configured.

Comment: If your loop runs faster than the desired pulse frequency, then the fact that you're generating the first 100ms (ish) of the waveform over and over again will become a problem